# Strange artifacts appear when drawing outlines of letter shapes with sharp corners. How to avoid them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm currently using HTML5's canvas to render a string using the **Impact** font. This works fine, but the stroke appears to be bleeding out of the whole text area. Is there any way to fix this?

Code and render can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/5uczpa1k/

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "80px Impact";
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.strokeText("A TEXT DEMO", 50, 150);
ctx.fillText("A TEXT DEMO", 50, 150);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a `miterLimit` - this defines a limit on the ratio of the miter (corner) length to the stroke-width used to draw a miter join. When the limit is exceeded, the join is converted from a miter to a bevel:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "80px Impact";
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.miterLimit = 2;
ctx.strokeText("A TEXT DEMO", 50, 150);
ctx.fillText("A TEXT DEMO", 50, 150);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Would be a better answer if it explained *why*. (Also, an alternative would be to set `lineJoin` instead.)

Comment: I’m not 100% sure but I think this relates to not being able to control where the text stroke is being rendered from in html5, i.e. inner, outer, center. It looks like this implementation of text stroke uses an inner stroke. It would be interesting to see if the same bleed appears with an outer stroke.

Comment: @user3840170, how would you use `lineJoin`? I tried `lineJoin: bevel` but it did nothing?

Comment: @NasserAhmed try ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

Comment: Looks like this error is still coming up with Chrome on Android devices even with ctx.miterLimit = 2. See here: https://pasteboard.co/NDMjz0DP5qwj.png. What could be the issue here?

Comment: looking at that image, the initial problems with "spikes" extending out from the text have now been replaced with the outline bleeding internally into the text. Could you post your updated code which produced that image?

Answer (score -1):

```
ctx.lineJoin = 'bevel';
```

The stroke is always drawn half inside and half outside, unless you make the necessary calculations to do something different yourself and draw two separate shapes, one for the fill and one for the outline. The default half-and-half approach is applied even when the lineWidth is an odd number, in which case the browser will attempt to draw halfway between two actual pixels, resulting in blurring and loss of colour intensity (unless you shift the canvas by 0.5px in both dimensions by applying a translation transform). This is more of a problem when translucency is involved. You have an opaque fill being performed after the stroke. So the net effect is that your outline  effectively becomes "outside" but its apparent width is half of the width stated in the code.